# How to set motion layout transition to one activity to another

Tags: android-animation, android-transitions, android-motionlayout, activity-transition

I'm traying to set motion layout transition one activity to another but I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Start the second activity, but make background transparent (also in themes), and override activity transition animations.
Then create motionlayout in second activity's xml, then make it automatically start.